# SAS - assign decimal to float variable

Tags: sas

In following SAS code, b and c are float variables.

```
if a=0 then do
  b = .;
  c= .;
end;
```

Does b and c now have value as 0.0?

Thanks

Comment: Technically nothing has a value as you have a syntax error.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a dot indicates a [missing value](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002316433.htm).

Comment: thanks! In my python translation, will use it as None.

Comment: @Pankaj You're welcome. Please consider to accept my answer on SO.